# Is there a way to have beta merged into master without adding an extra merge commit?

Tags: git, github

We have GitHub repository with branches 2 branches main and beta.
main: production server pipeline and beta: testing server pipeline.
When feature is required, we create a branch feature1

Step 1:

```
git checkout feature1
Make the changes
git add .
git commit -am "Feature is created"
git push origin feature1
```

Step 2:

Pull request: we create a pull request from feature1 to beta.
Beta pipeline gets triggered and all ok with testing server.

```
git checkout beta
git checkout pull origin beta
```

Step 3:

Create another pull request from beta to main or feature1 to main.
Here github creates a problem that beta branch goes 1 commit ahead and/or behind the main branch.

What is the correct flow to avoid this problem? Is a branching approach correct for maintaining production and testing servers?

How should I push changes to testing and production servers using pull requests without encountering issues with commit ahead and behind problems?

Comment: Can you please explain the following points : in what context do you see that "beta is 1 commit ahead and/or behind main" ? why is that a problem ?

Comment: @LeGEC I create a pull request from beta to main, that creates a new merge commit, and beta goes 1 commit behind the main.

Comment: would you want `main` to go to the exact same commit as `beta` ? something like `git checkout main && git merge --ff-only beta` ?

Comment: @LeGEC Yes but I want it to do it via pull request with approval. GitHub creates one extra commit on merge and then beta goes 1 commit behind. What is the perfect flow for testing and production branches?

Comment: @LeGEC Done. Changed.

Comment: But the question remains why you think "beta branch goes 1 commit ahead and/or behind the main branch" is a _problem_. This seems like you're just making up the idea that it's a problem.

Comment: @matt I think beta(testing branch) should sync with the main branch, it should not show that message it's behind or ahead, Or do all teams work like that if there are production and testing environments?

Comment: If you merge A into B then by definition B is ahead because B has a commit (the merge commit) that A doesn't have. That's simply what merging is. So what?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I figured it out as below. I am maintaining 2 branches main and beta, which serve as branches for the production and testing server with CI/CD pipeline.

1. Create a beta branch from the main branch.

   ```
   git checkout -b beta
   ```
2. Create a feature branch

   ```
    git checkout -b feature/branch1
   ```
3. Once the feature branch is developed, push changes on the remote.

   ```
    git add -A   

    git commit -m "Feature is created"   

    git push origin feature/branch1
   ```
4. Create a pull request from the feature branch to beta/testing server branch. Approve and merge the pull request.
5. Once testing is completed on beta/testing server, create another pull request from beta to main. Approve and merge the pull request.
6. Once all changes are pushed to production server, we need to make sure that beta/testing server branch stays in sync with main branch.

   ```
   git checkout main

   git pull origin main

   git checkout beta

   git merge main

   git push -f origin beta
   ```
7. Now you can delete feature branch on local and remote

   ```
   git branch -d feature/branch1

   git push origin --delete feature/branch1
   ```

Comment: @LeGEC Thank you for your help. Please check the answer. I am doing this way.

Comment: @matt Thank you for your help. Please check the answer. I am doing this way.